# In "FirebaseFirestore", instead of a link to an image, something incomprehensible is saved

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Clicking on `setupBtn` saves the following `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9138f83` instead of image links.

I think the whole problem is in this line
`Uri download_uri = Uri.parse(task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());`

Tell me what the problem is and how to fix it.

Complete code for `Activity`

```
public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CircleImageView setupImage;
    private Uri mainImageURI = null;

    private String user_id;
    private boolean isChanged = false;

    private EditText setupName;
    private Button setupBtn;
    private ProgressBar setupProgress;

    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

        Toolbar setupToolbar = findViewById(R.id.setupToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(setupToolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Account Setup");

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        user_id = Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        setupImage = findViewById(R.id.setup_image);
        setupName = findViewById(R.id.setup_name);
        setupBtn = findViewById(R.id.setup_btn);
        setupProgress = findViewById(R.id.setup_progress);

        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        setupBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String user_name = setupName.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name) && mainImageURI != null) {

                String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                setupProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("profile_image").child(user_id + ".jpg");
                image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        Uri download_uri = Uri.parse(task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());

                        Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("name", user_name);
                        userMap.put("image", download_uri.toString());

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                            if(task1.isSuccessful()){

                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(mainIntent);
                                finish();

                            }else {

                                String error = task1.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Firestore Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                            setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        });


                    }else {

                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Image Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        setupImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SetupActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Pre D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SetupActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                } else {BringImagePicker();}

            }else {BringImagePicker();}

        });
    }

    private void BringImagePicker() {

        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(SetupActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mainImageURI = result.getUri();
                setupImage.setImageURI(mainImageURI);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem, I fixed the code to this one:

```
image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot ->
                                image_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {

                                    String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                                    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    userMap.put("name", user_name);
                                    userMap.put("image", downloadUrl);

                                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                                        if (task1.isSuccessful()) {

                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                                            finish();

                                        } else {

                                            String error = task1.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Firestore Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }

                                        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    });

                                }));
                    } else {

                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Image Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

task.getResult() is depreciated, replace the code with

```
image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            final String downloadUrl = uri.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What is the "filePath"?

Comment: suppose to be image_path, I have edited the code

Comment: `uri.getDownloadUrl().toString();` This line does not work, writes `Cannot resolve method 'getDownloadUrl' in 'Uri`

Comment: try uri.toString()